# Using long int in PHP

Tags: php, int, unsigned-long-long-int

I am trying this out, but am unable to store large value

```
$var = rand(100000000000000,999999999999999);
echo $var; // prints a 9 digit value(largest possible)
```

How to get a desired value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP ints are typically 32 bits. Other packages provide higher-precision ints: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 20):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.
>
> ...
>
> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead.

[BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) and [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) are the (only?) way to manipulate this limitation.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to work with very large numbers I have found success with BC Math. Here is a link to everything you need to know:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate the number and manipulate as a native type, you can't with most PHP installations (either you have 32 or 64 bit `int`s and nothing else), as the other answers have already stated. However, if you are just generating a number and want to pass it around a possible trick is to just concatenate strings:

```
$var = rand(0,PHP_INT_MAX).str_pad(rand(0, 999999999), 9, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $var;
```

On a platform in which PHP uses a 32 bit integer, this allows you to get a near random integer (as a string) that is bigger than 32 bits ( > 10 decimal places). Of course, there is a bias in this construction which means you won't cover all the numbers with the same probability. The limits of the `rand()` calls obey normal decimal rules so its simple to adjust the upper bound of the number you want.

If all you're doing is storing/transmitting/showing this value, the string will be just fine. Equality and greater/less than tests will also work. Just don't do any math with it.