# Random number that is 15 characters long and positive

Tags: php, random

I am trying to make random numbers that are exactly 15 characters long and positive using php. I tried `rand(100000000000000, 900000000000000)` but it still generates negatives and numbers less than 15. Is there another function I am missing that can do this, or should I just use `rand(0, 9)` 15 times and concatenate the results?

Comment: For what it's worth, `rand` isn't broken, it's just that the numbers you are using are larger then the size of an `int` on your machine which is why you're seeing odd results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using long int in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647125/using-long-int-in-php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$i = 0;
$tmp = mt_rand(1,9);
do {
    $tmp .= mt_rand(0, 9);
} while(++$i < 14);
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max ) is the way to go. I would use this answer. +1

Comment: @ROYFinley what is special about `mt_rand()` ?

Comment: @ZOLDIK : Before [PHP 7.1 there were issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760905/1291879). These have now been resolved with `rand()` becoming an alias for `mt_rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a 32 bit platform. To handle these integers, you need a 64bits platform.

You can do the rand two times and save it as a string, like this:

```
$num1 = rand(100000,999999);
$num2 = rand(100000,999999);
$num3 = rand(100,999);
$endString = $num1.$num2.$num3;
```

PS. I like tiggers solution better than mine.

Comment: safe to go till 2bil (10chr) so a mt_rand for 7 digits and another one for 8 digits will do it, also 99999999 instead of 9000000

Comment: You are right. I wasn't sure about the number, so I played it safe.

Comment: max=2,147,483,647 so 9 effective digits

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
function moreRand($len) { 
    $str = mt_rand(1,9);
    for($i=0;$i<$len-1;$i++) { 
        $str .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $str;
}
echo moreRand(15);
```

Edit: If you want to shave .00045s off your execution time,

```
 function randNum() { return abs(rand(100000000000000, 900000000000000)); }
```

Comment: Keep in mind this could return 0 as the first 'digit', which technically would be a 14 digit number.

Comment: Whoops. Attention deficit. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that this will return a string, not an actual integer value.

```
function randNum($length)
{
    $str = mt_rand(1, 9); // first number (0 not allowed)
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i++)
        $str .= mt_rand(0, 9);

    return $str;
}

echo randNum(15);
```