# Difference between mt_rand() and rand()

Tags: php, performance, optimization, random

What is the difference between using `mt_rand($min, $max)` and `rand($min, $max)` about the speed?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Update

Since PHP 7.1 `mt_rand` has superseded `rand` completely, and `rand` was made an alias for `mt_rand`. The answer below focuses on the differences between the two functions for older versions, and the reasons for introducing `mt_rand`.

---

## Speed was not why `mt_rand` was introduced!

The `rand` function existed way before `mt_rand`, but it was deeply flawed. A PRNG must get some entropy, a number from which it generates a sequence of random numbers. If you print out a list of ten numbers that were generated by `rand()` like so:

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;++$i)
    echo rand(), PHP_EOL;
```

The output can be used to work out what the `rand` seed was, and with it, you can predict the next random numbers. There are tools out there that do this, so google a bit and test it.

There's also an issue with `rand` relativily quickly showing patterns in its random numbers [as demonstrated here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#73730). A problem `mt_rand` seems to solve a lot better, too.

`mt_rand` uses a better randomization algorithm (Mersenne Twist), which requires more random numbers to be known before the seed can be determined *and* is faster. ***This does not mean that `mt_rand` is, by definition, faster than `rand` is***, this only means that the way the numbers are generated is faster, and appears to have no real impact on the function's performance, as other answers here have demonstrated.
Either way, have a look at [the `mt_srand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) and [the `srand` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php). I'm sure they'll contain some more info

If `mt_rand`'s algorithm translates in an increase in performance, then that's great for you, but it's a happy coincidence. TL;TR:

## `mt_rand` was introduced to fix the problems that exist in `rand`!

Comment: @PEMapModder The answer was written ~2 years ago, before `rand` was made an alias. WRT contents: it's main focus is explaining _why_ `mt_rand` was introduced initially (which is still relevant). For completeness sake, I'll add an update stating that `rand` is now an alias. Other than that, the information provided is still correct IMO

Comment: Note that mt_rand() is flawed as well, the seed can be recovered with [untwister](https://github.com/altf4/untwister), and can be used to calculate future (and past) values. In PHP 7, use `random_int()` and `random_bytes()` for security purposes.

Answer (score 34):

## Update (PHP 7.1):

> [`rand()` and `srand()` have now been made aliases to `mt_rand()` and `mt_srand()`, respectively.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases) This means that the output for the following functions have changes: `rand()`, `shuffle()`, `str_shuffle()`, and `array_rand()`.

That means that since version 7.1 there is no practical difference between both of them because [`rand` calls `mt_rand` internally](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L44).

---

## Before PHP 7.1:

Using `rand()` is not a bad practice if it not used for security purposes, I'm usually using `rand()` (habit?).

If you need an enormous amount of random numbers you will need `mt_rand` instead `rand`. `mt_rand` has a period of 2<sup>19937</sup> − 1, far better than `rand` (2<sup>32</sup>). Take a look to [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20140801002727/http://tjl.co/blog/code/followup-php-rand-vs-mt_rand/) about graphical pattern generation using `rand` and `mt_rand`.

**[Periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Periodicity) and [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) are the only reasons for using `mt_rand()` instead `rand()` and not security or speed improvements.**

Mathematically `mt_rand` have more [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29) and a greater [periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Periodicity) than `rand` (2<sup>19937</sup>−1 vs. 2<sup>32</sup>).

If you need a few random numbers and security is not a problem, `rand` will do the job (get a random number to decide firing a cleanup process).

---

## Testing speed improvements

In practice there is not much difference in speed between the two functions (maybe because PHP⇔C wrapper overhead?).

**PHP test code:**

```
<?php
for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
  $start = microtime(true);
  $sum = 0.0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++) {
    $sum += rand();
  }
  printf('[rand %d] Time: %.3f s%s', $c, microtime(true) - $start, PHP_EOL);
}
for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c++) {
  $start = microtime(true);
  $sum = 0.0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000000; $i++) {
    $sum += mt_rand();
  }
  printf('[mt_rand %d] Time: %.3f s%s', $c, microtime(true) - $start, PHP_EOL);
}
```

**Tests in PHP 7.0.19:**

```
$ php timing.php
[rand 0] Time: 4.658 s
[rand 1] Time: 4.664 s
[rand 2] Time: 4.654 s
[mt_rand 0] Time: 4.267 s
[mt_rand 1] Time: 4.255 s
[mt_rand 2] Time: 4.261 s
```

**Tests in PHP 5.4.45 (slower machine):**

```
$ php timing.php
[rand 0] Time: 10.862 s
[rand 1] Time: 10.889 s
[rand 2] Time: 10.615 s
[mt_rand 0] Time: 10.948 s
[mt_rand 1] Time: 9.883 s
[mt_rand 2] Time: 10.190 s
```

Only 6-9% and not 400% as claimed.

---

## Using for security purposes

But if your application needs a lot of entropy because security issues, you'll need a more secure way and [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) possibly is the best solution, does its work (far better but slower? we need security over speed?) [relying on openssl related issues](http://timoh6.github.io/2013/11/05/Secure-random-numbers-for-PHP-developers.html).

**Neither [`rand()` nor `mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) are safe enough**:

> **Caution** This function does not generate cryptographically secure
>   values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need
>   a cryptographically secure value, consider using `random_int()`,
>   `random_bytes()`, or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead.

There is PHP extensions like [`random_compat`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat), but I didn't recommend using them if it not necessary.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if the updates (PHP 7.1) are put at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll edit the answer at home.

Answer (score 4):

As of PHP 7.1 there is **no difference at all**. rand() is now an alias for mt_rand().

See http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php#migration71.incompatible.rand-srand-aliases

And more details: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rng_fixes

Answer (score 2):

PHP Manual on [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) states that it:

> which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides.

Comment: So why rand() exists?

Comment: @Marveylabs `rand()` is standard language construct that were in PHP for very long time (probably ported from `C` language). `mt_rand()` is somewhat newer as far as I know. That's why `mt_rand()` is called a `better rand` by Manual :)

Comment: @Forien: You're forgetting the problems with `rand` of old, vs `mt_rand` => the ease with which the seed can be deduced from the output, for example

Comment: @Forien: Please check the docs again, it's not the `mt_rand` function that is said to be faster, it's the _algorithm_ that it uses that is faster than the ***average*** libc `rand` function. That does not mean that this speed difference will translate to a performance difference in PHP... It only states that the PRNG will generate the numbers faster, nothing more, nothing less

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes, that means "faster" for system, not PHP. But if you don't see difference in PHP speed, but have better distribution and put less strain on system on the server, why don't use it?

Comment: @Forien: You should use it, of course. But the title of this question is _"What's the difference"_, to which you say `mt_rand` is faster. Which is only partly true. The better distribution and harder to guess seed is what the real difference is, [things I explained](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28760905/1230836), but you just don't mention that in your answer, which makes it incomplete and a possible source of misinformation (OP believes `mt_rand` is there solely for speed reasons, which is totally untrue)

Comment: @Forien: so, why exactly did you remove my edit? Do you still believe this quote to be true? Please read other answers.

Comment: @georg: The quote is probably true, but it's incomplete. What the quote states is that the Mersenne twist algo is four times faster than the PRNG algo in the _"average"_ libc `rand` function, which is what PHP's `rand` also uses. It does ***not*** mean (however, it sort of implies it) that `mt_rand` is therefore 4 times faster. It clearly isn't. It's an incomplete quote, and thus misleading information, even more than the vague quote on the docs page...

Comment: @georg Wherever my answer is true or false, I do not allow anyone, to post *their* words under my name. Plus, @OscarGarcia posted timings which shows `mt_rand` to be much faster for system, which goes right with statement that numbers are generated faster. It's separate matter from PHP speed and I never said that PHP runs faster with `mt_rand` over `rand`.

Comment: @Forien: Strange, the answer by OscarGarcia looks to me to say, and I'm quoting here, _"there is not much difference between the two functions"_. Also: any answer you post here falls under a creative commons license, so edits are allowed, whether you like it or not

Comment: Note that this answer is obsolete. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41135653/3990767 for PHP 7.1 onward.

Answer (score -1):

They appear to be equal in speed:

```
function timeit($times, $func) {
    $t = microtime(1);
    while($times--) $func();
    return microtime(1) - $t;
}

echo PHP_OS, " ", phpversion(), "\n";
echo timeit(100000, function() {    rand(0,1000); }), "\n";
echo timeit(100000, function() { mt_rand(0,1000); }), "\n";
```

Results for OSX Mavericks and VirtualBox'ed Ubuntu 11:

```
Darwin 5.5.19
0.038038969039917
0.033117055892944

Linux 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10
0.031459093093872
0.031935214996338
```

If these measures are correct, the manual comment mentioned elsewhere should be considered wrong/obsolete.

Comment: The claim that `mt_rand` is four times faster is a horrible blanket statement that is indeed very likely to be outdated. The _"average"_ libc `rand` has probably changed a hundred times since that sentence was added to the PHP docs anyway... Besides, `mt_rand` wasn't added for speed reasons, it was added because of the inherent flaws in the old `rand` PRNG. speed gain was _never_ the main reason for `mt_rand`, that's what everyone seems to be forgetting here.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: actually, the whole debate appears to be much ado about nothing to me. For "weak" randomness ("shuffle cards") it doesn't matter if you use rand or mt_ and in serious applications (cryptography) you should use neither.

Comment: You're right. It's a bit of a pointless debate. I just got carried away by the answers all failing to mention the better distribution of `mt_rand`, and only focusing on speed, but then, that was the OP's question. That, and the attitude of some users got me worked up over nothing... I'm with you though, OP accepted the better answer, and so I'll leave this one be