# PHP: Multiple Unique Random Integers In A Specific Range

Tags: php, random, unique

I want to create 8 random integers, that are unique and in the range between 0 and 99.

Is there a neater solution, than the one that I thought of?

```
<?php


do {

  $rnd1 = rand(0,99);
  $rnd2 = rand(0,99);
  $rnd3 = rand(0,99);
  $rnd4 = rand(0,99);
  $rnd5 = rand(0,99);
  $rnd6 = rand(0,99);

} while (($rnd1 == $rnd2) || 
         ($rnd1 == $rnd3) || 
         ($rnd1 == $rnd4) || 
         ($rnd1 == $rnd5) || 
         ($rnd1 == $rnd6) || 
         ($rnd2 == $rnd3) || 
         ($rnd2 == $rnd4) || 
         ($rnd2 == $rnd5) || 
         ($rnd2 == $rnd6) || 
         ($rnd3 == $rnd4) || 
         ($rnd3 == $rnd5) || 
         ($rnd3 == $rnd6) || 
         ($rnd4 == $rnd5) || 
         ($rnd4 == $rnd6) || 
         ($rnd5 == $rnd6)    );


?>
```

Comment: `$range = range(0, 99); shuffle($range); $rand_ints = array_slice($range, 0, 8);`

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below.
It will create an array containing 8 random values between 0 and 99 while checking if they have been added already to ensure they are unique across.

```
$numbers = array();
while ( count($numbers) <= 8 ) {
    $x = mt_rand(0,99); 
    if ( !in_array($x,$numbers) ) {
        $numbers[] = $x;
    }
}
print_r($numbers);
```

Also see these two Q&A's about using `mt_rand` vs. `rand`
[Difference between mt_rand() and rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760650/difference-between-mt-rand-and-rand)
[What's the disadvantage of mt_rand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808021/whats-the-disadvantage-of-mt-rand)

Comment: Also note that we have [`random_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

Comment: My solution is faster than checking with `in_array` every time you generate a number.

Answer (score 1):

This is an optimized version that relies on the array indexes. The complexity of this solution is linear rather than n<sup>2</sup> as in @AlexAndrei's answer. It relies on using array indexes as the guarantee there are no duplicates so there is no need to add the overhead of `in_array`.

```
$random_numbers = [];

do {
  $rand = rand(0, 99);
  $random_numbers[$rand] = $rand;
} while( count($random_numbers) < 9 );

$random_numbers = array_values($random_numbers); // This strips the keys

print_r($random_numbers);
```

If you are using a `foreach` you can even drop the `array_values` call which would also increase the speed of your code, but the numbers in the array will be in the form: `[ a => a, b => b, ... ]`

Comment: Though you can use `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()` which should theoretically speed up the avarage generation process because of `mt_rand()`'s higher entropy.

Answer (score -1):

```
$rnds = [];

do {
  $newRnd = rand(0, 99);
  $rnds[] = $newRnd;
} while(in_array($newRnd, $rnds) && count($rnds) < 9);

print_r($rnds);
```

Comment: If there is a duplicate, this would only do another itteration of the (do while) loop, not actually remove/overwrite it. Stub the `rand` with `5` and you will see that I am correct.