# Random value options

Tags: php, random

I want to pick some value from array randomly, but I'm not sure about best way to do it(in terms of performance etc). I'm only a beginner, so I don't know many ways to random values and don't know how they affect performance and exact differences of them. For example: "mt_rand" is four times faster than "rand" function.

If I have this array of names:

```
$myarrayofnames = ["Marcelle","Caroll","Kristina","Tisha","Filomena","Vesta","Josphine"];
```

And I want to pick from them, what are my options?

Comment: use `shuffle()` `shuffle($myarrayofnames);` for random, how many values do you want to get randomly. ?

Comment: Only one... so, I do like this: `$shuffle($myarrayofnames);` and then return?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get random value out of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643431/how-to-get-random-value-out-of-an-array)

Comment: `$randomNo = array_rand($myarrayofnames,1);
echo $myarrayofnames[$randomNo];` just do ir

Comment: nop, you can also follow the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that *`mt_rand()`* and *`rand()`* just for generate random no.

> *[From the Manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) mt_rand — Generate a better random value*
>
> *[From the Manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) rand — Generate a random integer*

For your array you can use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) for getting random value.

**Example:**

```
$myarrayofnames = ["Marcelle","Caroll","Kristina","Tisha","Filomena","Vesta","Josphine"];
$randomNo = array_rand($myarrayofnames,1);
echo $myarrayofnames[$randomNo]; // this will print the random value
```

If you just want only one single value from your array than you can just pass `1` in second param.

If you want more than one value from your array than you can pass `no` as per your array index count. In this case [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will return an array.

*If you want to learn about the [Difference between mt_rand() and rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760650/difference-between-mt-rand-and-rand)*