# php excel setting wrong cell value

Tags: php, phpexcel

when i set a cell value like this

```
->setCellValue('O' . $currentRow, 12000000000000111702)
```

or

```
->setCellValue('O' . $currentRow, "12000000000000111702")
```

it is generating values 1.2E+19 i.e 12000000000000000000
can anyone tell me the reason ?

Comment: I think this is an Excel problem, not a php problem. Probably it's the formatting of the cell. When you're dealing with such huge numbers, it's "normal" to lose accuracy. Usually Excel works to about 15 significant figures or so

Comment: In fact: If I copy/paste the number 12000000000000111702 into an Excel cell, it changes it automatically to 12000000000000100000

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647125/using-long-int-in-php

Comment: if you put the same number into Excel directly, it will be truncated to 0.120000000000001. So PHP will not be losing your Excel users any more precision than they would lose anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this value to be retained exactly "as is" rather than converted to a float (because it's too big for a PHP int), then you'll need to set the value explicitly as a string using

```
->setCellValueExplicit('O' . $currentRow, "12000000000000111702", PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)
```

You don't actually need to specify PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING because setCellValueExplicit() defaults to that anyway.

Comment: +1 In fact, the piece of data looks like a numeric code rather than a pure integer.