# resetting AUTO_INCREMENT value in MySQL avoiding race condition

Tags: mysql

I know that I can reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value in MySQL using

```
ALTER TABLE fooo AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

However, can I avoid changing the value when the table is not empty? Alternatively, can I automatically and **atomically** set it to the current maximum value + 1?

### Background

I have a queue table that is filled by various processes with simple data that is processed by another, *single* process. The latter deletes items it has processed. It is likely that the table becomes completely empty, although new data will come in quickly.

Currently the auto increment value is over 1,000,000,000 and sooner or later this will lead to nasty integer overflows in the processes. This is why I'm looking for a way to reset the autoinc value for a busy table (within the process that consumes/deletes the rows in the table).

NOTE: As this is a queue, I must absolutely avoid to set the autoinc value to a value lower than currently existing data.

Comment: Changing the data type to `bigint` will solve this issue without anything else you need to do, Signed bigint max value is `9.223.372.036.854.775.807`

Comment: @juergend, any reason not to use unsigned?

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Almost all public APIs are designed using signed INT to be compatible. I would use it if I don't really need unsigned. It is a real pain casting all API calls to `unsigned` in your program.

Comment: @juergend: the problem is not within MySQL, but the PHP script consuming the data

Comment: @UdoG: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8647177/575376

Comment: @UdoG: From the post I linked before: *64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18.* ...Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MyISAM, simply reset to 1 with `ALTER`, and it will automatically use the next highest.

For InnoDB, to reset and use the next highest value atomically:

```
LOCK TABLES table WRITE;
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 1) FROM table;
// Use value from SELECT in the ALTER
ALTER TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 99;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit that MySQL is not the right tool for your needs. For queues there are better systems like [RabitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) for example. You could use [Redis](http://redis.io/) to save data in a very fast way.

It's better to use the right tool for a problem.

Another way for MySQL is to change column type to a format with more possible ids like `bigint` for example.

Comment: RabbitMQ is used for other stuff, but in this case we're talking about >10,000 items per second. To use RabbitMQ for that would be overkill. The data is anyway stored *permanently* in the MySQL database after processing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about `LOCK TABLES fooo WRITE`, then `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fooo` to check if the table is empty and reset the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value if it is, then `UNLOCK TABLES`. Repeat until you happen to lock the table while it's empty, and thus manage to perform the reset.

Comment: That could work. It's just that I have had very bad experiences with LOCK TABLES in MySQL (unstable MySQL when something goes wrong during the LOCK).